# Solidity codes and there Theoretical information

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

Hello everyone i am learning solidity development from freecodescamp.org i don't have any coding background but now i cant find information about all the codes (syntex) like i want to understand every codes and functionality of code for example () , {} , [] , function, array what are there functionality and purpose theoretical information of codes if someone can help me i will b very thankful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a coding background it's probably best just to follow the courses and let them introduce these things as it progresses, but if you need to look things up, the best place to start is https://docs.soliditylang.org.

There are many other good resources but make sure they're up-to-date. Solidity is constantly changing and evolving, so even good information at the time can become outdated. You won't have that issue with https://docs.soliditylang.org